# Cannot delete folder

Tags: windows-7

I cannot delete a folder "test" on my desktop. This folder is on desktop but in directory "desktop" there is no folder with name "test"

When I try to open "test" it it gives me an error. something like this: "delete folder references an inaccessible location"

Comment: Is this on a company computer (domain joined) or on a home machine? Are you logged in as Administrator (or administrator account) or a local standard user?

Comment: Sounds like you have filesystem corruption.  This isn't a permission problem, the folder, no longer actually exists.

Comment: I hope you have tried restarting the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run chkdsk  /f on your system as administrator.  Start - cmd - right click, run as administrator, then type chkdsk /f and hit enter.  It will ask if you want to run at next reboot.  Type Y and hit enter, then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Check the hidden folder : C:\Users\Public\Desktop